# WebGL update dynamic meshes

Tags: javascript, webgl, rendering, mesh

I have a collection of verticies (a mesh) that is updated each frame, think of a flower that grows and has to be drawn on the screen.

I currently render the mesh by binding the Float32Array, that containins the mesh verticies, each tick, so each frame the buffer is uploaded to the GPU.

Is there any way to update the mesh without re-uploading the buffer? Each frame contains the new points that are added and the old points that stay the same, is there any "gl_pushVerticies" method?

Answer (score 1):

The line *"Each frame contains new points are added and the old points stay the same"* **is the key here......

As a part of the 'flower' stays the same and 'new' vertices are added, I would create one big vertex buffer with all vertices (all parts) in it (the complete flower) and draw it partially by using the count of (for example) `void gl.drawElements(mode, count, type, offset);`

This way you don't need to manipulate any vertex buffer.

For example using indices

```
// create the vertex buffer with all vertices (complete object)
// for example 56 vertices
```

frame1:

```
// instead of drawing the complete object, you draw only 24 vertices
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 24, 0);
```

frame2:

```
// instead of drawing the complete object, you draw only 48 vertices
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 48, 0);
```

frame3:

```
// instead of drawing the complete object, you draw only 56 vertices
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 56, 0);
```

etc.....

Comment: So, once a vertex buffer is created and bound it can be updated?

Comment: It sure can be modified, but you rather not want it. Instead of adding vertices to the buffer, you use a full buffer en just draw not all vertices but only some parts.. check the example with the frames. I'll add some extra info.

Comment: I understand, but I don't know the future points before I reach that specific frame as the points positions is based on user input, so I actually have to update the vertex array with the new point positions once they are generated.

Comment: That I missed in the question. Instead of creating a buffer with a `Float32Arrray`, you create the buffer with a size. With the [bufferSubData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferSubData) you can modify the vertex buffer after it is created.